# JAXB Error, sample xsd docs

Tags: xsd, jaxb

I'm getting a JAXB errors when I run "xjc -p foo.bar bmw.xsd":

[ERROR] A class/interface with the same name "foo.bar.Fault" is already in use.
  line 16 of bmw.xsd

[ERROR] (Relevant to above error) another one is generated from here.
  line 26 of abc.xsd

Is it related to the two 'fault' elements clashing? If so, what do I do to fix?

bmw.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  elementFormDefault="qualified"    targetNamespace="http://foo.com/bmw" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bmw="http://foo.com/bmw">
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  schemaLocation="abc.xsd"/>
<xs:element name="rule">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="bmw:customer"/>
    <xs:element ref="bmw:schemaName"/>
    <xs:element ref="bmw:schemaVersion"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="customer" type="xs:integer"/>
<xs:element name="schemaName" type="xs:NCName"/>
<xs:element name="schemaVersion" type="xs:decimal"/>
<xs:element name="fault">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="bmw:faultcode"/>
    <xs:element ref="bmw:faultstring"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="faultcode" type="xs:integer"/>
<xs:element name="faultstring" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

abc.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bmw="http://foo.com/bbs">
<xs:import namespace="http://foo.com/bmw" schemaLocation="bmw.xsd"/>
<xs:element name="Envelope">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="env:Header"/>
    <xs:element ref="env:Body"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Header">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="bmw:rule"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Body">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="env:Fault"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Fault">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="bmw:fault"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options when resolving the name conflict.

**Option #1 - Schema Annotation**

You can annotate the XML schema to resolve the name conflict:

```
<xs:element name="Fault">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <jaxb:class name="Fault2" />
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="bmw:fault"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

**abc.xsd**

Refer to the schema annotation on the "Fault" element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bmw="http://foo.com/bbs"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jaxb:version="2.1">
    <xs:import namespace="http://foo.com/bmw" schemaLocation="bmw.xsd" />
    <xs:element name="Envelope">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="env:Header" />
                <xs:element ref="env:Body" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Header">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="bmw:rule"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Body">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="env:Fault" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Fault">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
                <jaxb:class name="Fault2" />
            </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="bmw:fault"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**Option #2 - External Bindings File**

Instead of modifying the XML schema you can also use an external bindings file:

**bindings.xml**

```
<jaxb:bindings 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="abc.xsd">
            <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='Fault']">
                <jaxb:class name="Fault2"/>
            </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

The xjc command would be:

```
xjc -d out -b bindings.xml abc.xsd
```

---

**Package Name**

To control the package name you can either pass it as a parameter to the XJC command:

```
xjc -d out -b bindings.xml -p com.foo.bar abc.xsd
```

Or amend the bindings file.

Comment: another Q if u don't mind...when I run xjc -b bindings.xml abc.xsd, it runs, and I get two package structures. One of the package structures is org.xmlsoap.schemas.soap... I think I need to integrate this structure into my current code base, so I may use the classes in this structure. How do I integrate these classes? The other package structure has a similar structure of my current code base, so I don't have the issue...

Comment: You want all the generated classes to be in the same package?

Comment: my main code base is like com.bmw.foo....I would like all of the generated classes to fall somewhere in there

Comment: also, it is normal that xjc is generating two separate package structures?

Comment: i made another bindings file, and added: <jxb:schemaBindings><jxb:package name="example"></jxb:schemaBindings>
and i still get two package structures, but I can make one of the two structures what i want. Is this correct? Also, is there a way to combine the two bindings files?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your error is related to the clash.  You can fix this with a [customized binding](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html).  A customized binding is a way of telling JAXB to do something other than what it naturally would do.  Try looking into the [class](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html#wp148576) tag in an external binding file if you cannot annotate the XSD yourself.

Comment: @justkt - jaxb:javaType is for data types, jaxb:class is used to control the generated class name.

Comment: what path should I explore, the javaType or annotation?

Comment: @bmw0128 - I answered the question (see Blaise's comment and my edit, it should be class not javaType) assuming either that you could not or would not want to change the .xsd.  If you have no problem changing the XSD, annotation is simple.  If you want to keep the JAXB annotations out of your XSD, try an external bindings file.  Either way, you use the class tag.

Comment: i think you are saying annotation and doing a binding file are the same, but i must use 'class' in either case....thx

Comment: @bmw0128 - yes, they have the same effect.  The article I linked to explains it very well.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include how to change the name using an external binding file.

Comment: @bmw0128 - given Blaise's comment, his answer now includes the information in my answer and is everything you want!